# Satellizer close popup event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, popup, satellizer

I found when I tried to login with satellizer, then I selected twitter, then I closed the popup, I could see toastr error and page refreshed (which is correct).
But when I tried to login with another social media (except twitter), then I closed the popup, I could not see any toastr message, and main page was not refreshed.
does satellizer only detect popup closing on oauth 1?
How can I detect if satellizer login popup has been closed?

I am new on this. I really need your help..

thanks

Stephanie Martin

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no event for this, though I've found a way to track it.
Satellizer sets the opened window to $window.popup, so watching that will help.

I'm using an interval like this

```
var intervalId = $interval(function() {
  if (!$window.popup.parent) {
    console.log('closed window!');
    $interval.cancel(intervalId);
  }
}, 200);
```

You will need to add a variable to watch that it wasn't closed by login or cancel.

Answer (score 0):

which version are you using? In the latest version the promise is rejected if  you  close the popup window. 
They have an example where you can see it in action 
 https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/client/controllers/login.js